# How to map pixels to values in a new image with python?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to map an image to a velocity model, where the colors represent the velocities, so I read an image using OpenCV, take its dimensions, create an array of velocities within a certain range and try to recreate the image with these values, I saw an algoirthm very similar in matlab that works:

`   vi=1000;
    vf=4200;
    M=imread('modelo_vr_2500x300.png');

```
Lx=size(M,1);
Ly=size(M,2);

N=M(1:Lx,1:Ly,1);

cor2=0:255;
vel2=cor2/256*(vf-vi)+vi; 
V=zeros(size(N));
for i=1:length(cor2)   
    V=V+vel2(i)*(N==cor2(i));
end
imagesc(V)
colorbar`
```

So I tried to adapt it to Python, but it doesn't seem to work, all that I get is an image totally black, but if I print V, the new image, it has values, but they are quite high. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, could anyone help?

import CV2
    # read image
    img = cv2.imread("figures/teste03-06B.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    # get dimensions of image
    dimensions = img.shape

```
# height = Ly, width = Lx, number of channels in image = Ch
Ly = img.shape[0]
Lx = img.shape[1]
Ch = img.shape[2]

N=img[0:Ly, 0:Lx, 0:Ch]

print('Image Dimension    : ',dimensions)
print('Image Height       : ',Ly)
print('Image Width        : ',Lx)
print('Number of Channels : ',Ch) 

cv2.imshow("Display window", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Display window")

import numpy as np

vi=2000
vf=6000
color=np.array(range(256))

vel=((color/256)*(vf-vi))+vi

V = np.zeros_like(img)

for i in range(0,len(color)):
if N[i]==color[i]:
    V=V+vel[i]
else:
    V=V
print(V)

cv2.imshow("Display window", V)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow("Display window")`
```

It doesn't give any error message, just doesn't work as it should, I have no idea why...

Comment: There seems to be a normalization issue, i.e. like you said the values are too large in your array. But I don't really get the formula you are using to calculate your speed in the first place since it's obvious that it will yield these large values. Maybe try to use `cv2.normalize`?

Comment: `color` will be an array of `int64` as a result of `color=np.array(range(256))` then you divide the integers by 256 which will give you zero.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, it is not, if I print 'vel' I can see the values, they are ok. It seems to me the problem was the translation from Matlab to Python, where  N==color[i] is a comparison, not an atribution.

Comment: Oh, ok, cool. If you have solved it, add your own answer and mark it as correct.

Comment: @MarkSetchell   I haven't solved it yet, I just rewrote the code to what it should be. Now it is giving me another error. "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: By the way, the code I was "translating" was this one:                                         v  vi=1000;
    vf=4200;
    M=imread('modelo_vr_2500x300.png'); 

    Lx=size(M,1);
    Ly=size(M,2);

    N=M(1:Lx,1:Ly,1);

    cor2=0:255;
    vel2=cor2/256*(vf-vi)+vi; 
    V=zeros(size(N));
    for i=1:length(cor2)   
        V=V+vel2(i)*(N==cor2(i));
    end
    imagesc(V)
    colorbar

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste the code in there where it can be formatted properly and easily read. Thank you.

Comment: Also, consider adding the `matlab` tag to attract the right folk.

Comment: Nvm, I asked a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
new_image = vel[img]
```

But you probably want to normalize vel first. Some variant of:

```
vel = vel/max(vel) * 255
vel = vel.astype(dtype=np.uint8)
```

I think that should work.